# Replication problems after server upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

In transactional replication - first 8000 rows of snapshot copies to subscriber snapshot then acts like it completed successfully.

Publication table has 21 million rows. Snapshot says completed successfully then we get the error "cannot find row at the subscriber" when transaction replication begins.

This is on a new 64 bit server running SQL Server 2005 Standard 64 bit SP3 with Cumulative Update 4. We have a standalone distributor also.

We upgraded the server / OS to Windows 2008 R2 64 bit and SQL Server from 32 to 64bit with the Cumulative Update 4 to take care of the paging issue/bug.

Has anyone ever ran into this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Could any operations be altering the values of the primary key columns of the table?

That error can be generated when a replicated update or delete statement cannot find a specific PK value.